# Showing confirmation message on delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a simple mvc application which perform the CRUD functionality to manage UserDetials. I need to show a confirmation box when trying to delete a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a submit handler with javascript to the form that is performing the deletion. Here's an example with jquery:

Assuming the following delete form:

```
<%: Html.BeginForm("Destroy", "Product", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { id = "deleteForm" }) { %>
    <%: Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete product" />
<% } %>
```

You could use jquery to attach a [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler and ask for user confirmation:

```
$(function() {
    $('#deleteForm').submit(function() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product');
    });
});
```